# pointer to string literal

Tags: c++, pointers, character

**char * ptr="coding";**

Here **ptr** is a character pointer which is pointing to the first character of the string enclosed in **" "**, that is ptr is pointing to address of **'c'**.

1. In pointers-->  * Operator is used to getting the values that are stored on
   the address pointed by the pointer variable.

So here

On accessing ****ptr*** --> we get the **value which is stored in the address pointed by ptr**, as ptr is pointing to address of 'c', so on writing this code

```
 char * ptr="coding";
 cout<< *ptr;
```

we get the output: c

on accessing ****++ptr*** --> ++ptr increments the location by 1 , so on accessing *++ptr, we get the value which is stored in next loaction.So on writing this code

```
char * ptr="coding";
     cout<< *++ptr;
```

we get the output: o

**& operator** is used for getting the address that is **being pointed by pointer variable, here as ptr is pointing to 'c'** so on writing this code :

```
 const char* str = "Hello"; 

 cout << &str ;
```

we get the output: 0x7fff11d19cb0

Now when we write code:

```
 char * ptr="coding";
         cout<< ptr;
```

We get the output: coding

How is it printing a whole string, as **ptr** is only pointing to the address of the first character 'c'.
Where does **ptr** pointing to?
As ptr is a character pointer.

Comment: `char * ptr="coding";` should not compile in modern c++

Comment: Also, please pick only one of c or c++ depending on what you're using.

Comment: Text or string literals are constant, read-only values.  In C++ you need to declare the pointer, as a pointer to constant data:  `char const * ptr = "coding";`